RPC Error When Cloning Git Submodules in Docker Compose
I'm trying to build my GeoNode project using Docker Compose, but the build fails during the installation of requirements. The error seems to occur during the git clone process for the geonode-mapstore-client repository. Here's a snippet of the error:
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8) fatal: early EOF fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output × git clone --filter=blob
--quiet https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode-mapstore-client.git /usr/src/geonode/django-geonode-mapstore-client did not run successfully. exit code: 128

After that, the build fails again due to submodule cloning issues:
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/geosolutions-it/MapStore2.git' into submodule path '/usr/src/geonode/django-geonode-mapstore-client/geonode_mapstore_client/client/MapStore2' failed fatal: early EOF fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

Here’s my Dockerfile and Docker Compose setup:
FROM geonode/geonode-base:latest-ubuntu-22.04
LABEL GeoNode development team

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/{{project_name}}

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install curl wget unzip gnupg2 locales -y

RUN sed -i -e 's/# C.UTF-8 UTF-8/C.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    locale-gen
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
ENV LANG C.UTF-8

# add bower and grunt command
COPY src /usr/src/{{project_name}}/
WORKDIR /usr/src/{{project_name}}

#COPY src/monitoring-cron /etc/cron.d/monitoring-cron
#RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/monitoring-cron
#RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/monitoring-cron
#RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
#RUN service cron start

COPY src/wait-for-databases.sh /usr/bin/wait-for-databases
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/wait-for-databases
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/{{project_name}}/tasks.py \
    && chmod +x /usr/src/{{project_name}}/entrypoint.sh

COPY src/celery.sh /usr/bin/celery-commands
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/celery-commands

COPY src/celery-cmd /usr/bin/celery-cmd
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/celery-cmd

# Install "geonode-contribs" apps
# RUN cd /usr/src; git clone https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode-contribs.git -b master
# Install logstash and centralized dashboard dependencies
# RUN cd /usr/src/geonode-contribs/geonode-logstash; pip install --upgrade  -e . \
#     cd /usr/src/geonode-contribs/ldap; pip install --upgrade  -e .

RUN yes w | pip install --src /usr/src -r requirements.txt &&\
    yes w | pip install -e .

# Cleanup apt update lists
RUN apt-get autoremove --purge &&\
    apt-get clean &&\
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Export ports
EXPOSE 8000

# We provide no command or entrypoint as this image can be used to serve the django project or run celery tasks
# ENTRYPOINT /usr/src/{{project_name}}/entrypoint.sh

[ERROR] RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-9): Error decoding the received TLS packet
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/geosolutions-it/MapStore2.git' into submodule path 'MapStore2' failed

Has anyone experienced similar Git-related errors when building Docker images that use submodules? How can I avoid the cloning issue during the docker compose build?
What I've Tried:
Increasing Git buffer size: git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000
Forcing HTTP/1.1 for Git: git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1
Manually cloning the submodules locally, which seems to work, but the issue reappears in Docker.
Environment:
Docker version: 24.0.0
Base Image: geonode/nginx:1.25.3-latest
OS: Ubuntu 22.04

I'd normally recommend not running git commands in a Dockerfile at all.  (How will you force a rebuild if the main branch changes?  How will you build a test image from uncommitted changes?  How do you manage credentials for private repositories?)  It seems like there are a lot of extra parts in your Dockerfile; can you [edit] it to include only a [mcve]?  The only git command that's currently there seems to be commented out.

@DavidMaze thank you for your answer. git is used her throught pip install -e git:https .
